# deploying python qt project

Tags: python

can you tell me how do i deploy my project on qt designer. i am using windows and also how do i convert the .py files to standard .exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting ".py" to ".exe" would be like converting Java to ".exe" without using GCJ. Since the language doesn't compile to native code, you're just bundling the interpreter and a packed set of .py files together using the same mechanism self-extracting .zip files use.

The main tools I know of for doing this on Windows are:

- [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
- [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)
- [bbfreeze](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/bbfreeze/)
- [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Here are some docs on how to work around the common sticking-points with PyQt:

- [Py2Exe and PyQt](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt)
- [How-to: Deploying PyQt applications on Windows and Mac OS X](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/03/how-to-deploying-pyqt-applications-on-windows-and-mac-os-x.ars)
- [Deploying PyQt Applications](http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Deploying_PyQt_Applications)

Assuming you're doing this to simplify distribution, you'll probably also want to build an installer to bundle in any DLL dependencies. The two popular free choices for Windows are:

- [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (Open-source)
- [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) (Freeware)

Py2Exe comes with an example of how to use a silent InnoSetup installer to build a fake single-file EXE by silently extracting the program and DLLs to a temp folder and running them. There's an [example for NSIS](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/SingleFileExecutable) on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org)